# How to fix encoding for Dictionary<char, char>?

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, encoding

I created a simple `Dictionary<char, char>` that contains character combinations to replace local characters to ascii characters (ē -> e), but it does not work - when I see this dictionary in debug mode - I see, that local characters are wrong (instead of my local characters (latvian) I see some different characters)

I suspect it's something to do with encoding, although I don't know why is this happening and how to fix it...

if I make a simple `string text = "with some local characters ā ē ū";` - if I check this in debug mode, encoding seems to be correct...

here is the instantiation of my dictionary: [image: dictionary]

and here is what values appear in this dictionary after instantiation:
[image]

Comment: Your file encoding is wrong, most likely. Stick to unicode if you want to keep your sanity :)

Comment: Ascii character are 0 to 256 while Unicode characters are 16 bits.  Ascii will character will vary depending on the computer country settings.  It looks like you are using ascii and characters are changing due to the country settings.  Unicode characters will not change based on computer country settings.  If your string are ascii then the characters in the dictionary need to be ascii.  If your strings contain Unicode characters then your dictionary needs to be Unicode.

Comment: @jdweng ASCII characters are 0 to 127. Unicode characters are 0 to 0x10FFFF. Unicode has several encodings. C# `char` uses UTF-16, where one or two might be needed to encoding a Unicode codepoint.

Comment: Check that your source is encoding per the [C# language specification](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/9.1.htm). It must use one of the allowed Unicode encodings. UTF-8 is always allowed. (I'd say preferred.) Your editor should be able to tell you which your using and/or allow you to re-save it with a specific encoding.

Comment: @TomBlodget Ok, so I have two source files - in one of them - if I instantiate Dictionary object - it has one encoding, but in other source file - it gets another encoding... (just copy pasted the code between those two source files...) The only difference between two source files I see - is that one with the wrong encoding is having `static` class...

Comment: @TomBlodget Ok, I got it - it is a different encoding for source files... it's strange though, since both of those files where created from Visual Studio - don't get why they both didn't get the same encoding?! Anyway - I'll accept your answer If you will post it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your source is encoding per the [C# language specification](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/9.1.htm). It must use one of the allowed Unicode encodings. UTF-8 is always allowed. (I'd say preferred.) Your editor should be able to tell you which your using and/or allow you to re-save it with a specific encoding.

In Visual Studio, you can re-save the file with a specific encoding using File » Advanced Save Options…, then File » Save.